# Select2 The Result Cannot Be Load in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, mysqli, jquery-select2, codeigniter-3

When I type in my select box the result always show "The result cannot be load". I am using CodeIgniter for my framework and select2 in my select box and am a newbie in CodeIgniter and Select2. I have already search it through all articles that can be related to my problem but it still can't work. I think I messed my ajax but I don't know how and where I should fix it.

Here is my controller

```
<?php
    class Admin extends CI_Controller{
        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->model('admin_model');
        }

        function search_book(){
            $booksClue = $this->input->get('booksClue');
            $data_book = $this->admin_model->get_book($booksClue, 'id_book');
            echo json_encode($data_book);
        }

    }
?>
```

Here is my model

```
<?php
    class Admin_model extends CI_Model{

        function get_book($booksClue, $column){
            $this->db->select($column);
            $this->db->like('id_book', $booksClue);
            $data = $this->db->from('book')->get();
            return $data->result_array();
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is my view

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.searchingBook').select2({
                placeholder: 'Masukkan ID Buku',
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                allowClear: true,
                ajax:{
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/admin/searchbook",
                    dataType: "json",
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function(params){
                        return{
                            booksClue: params.term
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function(data){
                        var results = [];

                        $.each(data, function(index, item){
                            results.push({
                                id: item.id_book,
                                text: item.id_book
                            });
                        });
                        return{
                            results: results
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>ID Buku</b></td>
            <td> : </td>
            <td>
                <select class="searchingBook" style="width: 500px">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Big thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you think the panes in the Code Snippets feature are clearly labeled "JavaScript", "HTML", and "CSS"?   Answer:  because you can't run PHP in a browser.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your model function like below:

```
function get_book($booksClue, $column){
    $this->db->select($column);
    $this->db->from('book');
    $this->db->like('id_book', $booksClue);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(data)`  inside `processResults` function?

Comment: It isn't showing anything in my console. Should it resulting like id_book?

But when I check my Sources while input "D" word in select box it showing GET http://localhost:81/publisher/admin/searchbook?booksClue=D 404 (Not Found) jquery.js:8526. Does this matter with my problem?

Comment: ok i got the issue, you are using `searchbook` in ajax url which is not available in controller, controller function name is `search_book` so change ajax url with `localhost:81/publisher/admin/search_book?booksClue=D`